# Insert multiple dimension array codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have a problem when I insert data array from checkbox. I want to insert my data like this. This form is quiz:

> 1 | what's your color like? | red, blue
>
> 2 | what's your age? | 17

All of my question are array and the option are checkbox. I want implode my checkbox answer. Here my code:

**View**

```
<?php $i = 1;
foreach ($pertanyaan as $p) { ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="id_pertanyaan[]" value="<?= $p->id_pertanyaan ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="kategori[]" value="<?php $p->kategori_id ?>">
    <p><?php echo $i;
        echo ". " . $p->isi ?></p>
    <?php $array = explode(';', $p->opsi_jawaban); ?>
    <?php foreach ($array as $a) {
        if ($p->kategori_id == 1) {
            if ($a != "") { ?>
                <div class="radio">
                    <input type="radio" name="jawaban[<?= $i ?>]" value="<?= $a ?>"> <?= $a ?>
                </div>
            <?php }
        } elseif ($p->kategori_id == 2) {
            if ($a != "") { ?>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group form-material">
                                <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-primary">
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="jawaban[<?= $i ?>]" class="cek" data-fv-notempty="true" value="<?= $a ?>" data-fv-notempty-message="This is required">
                                    <label for="requiredCheckbox"><?= $a ?></label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group form-material">
                                <?php if ($a == 'lainnya') { ?>
                                    <input type="text" name="lainnya" class="form-control">
                                <?php } ?>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            <?php }
        } else { ?>
            <div class="form-group form-material">
                <input type="text" name="jawaban[<?= $i ?>]" class="form-control">
            </div>
    <?php }
    } ?>
<?php $i++;
} ?>
```

**Controller**

```
$pertanyaanid = $_POST['id_pertanyaan'];
$jawaban = $_POST['jawaban'];
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$this->load->database();
$id_investor = $this->db->insert_id();
$index = 1;
foreach ($pertanyaanid as $j) {
    $kat = $_POST['kategori'];
    if( $kat[$index] == 2)
    {
        $dataj = array(
            'pertanyaan_id' => $j,
            'jawaban' => $jawaban[$index],// trouble input
            'inv_id' => $id_investor,
            'created_at' => $now
        );
    }else 
    {
        $dataj = array(
            'pertanyaan_id' => $j,
            'jawaban' => $jawaban[$index],
            'inv_id' => $id_investor,
            'created_at' => $now
        );
    }
    $this->Survey_model->insertjawaban($dataj);  
    $index++;
}
```

Could you help me please or you have reference for my question? Because my current condition just insert like this:

> 1 | what's your color like? | blue
>
> 2 | what's your age? | 17

Here is my picture form:

[image]

Comment: please describe your problem with picture please.

Comment: your `color` & `age` are in `loop` & you want to insert it??

Comment: you want to insert any one radio button value & multiple checkbox values, so where is it multi dimensional array??

Comment: @KUMAR. I have update my question with picture. I want to insert the answer of quiz like a pictures.. my problem is when I insert data number two, I just insert one I just insert  **hijau**. How can I insert number two tobe **kuning, hijau**?

Comment: both `kuning`, `hijau` checkboxes are inserted in single column in the form of comma seperated values Yes,  or is it one question in one page or multiple questions in one page with submit button??

Comment: @KUMAR it is multiple question in one form. and for question checkbox inserted by implode. How is it?

Comment: have you solved your problem or not??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your View Code Like:-**

You must do all radio & checkbox `name[]` as an array like this.

```
<?php 
   //sql Query.
  //execute Query.

 foreach($types as $key=>$value){?> 

<input type="radio" name="option1[$key]" value="A">A<br>

<br><br>


<label>
    <input type="checkbox"  value="<?php echo $value['name'] ?>"  name="option2[$key]" />
    <span class="text"><?php echo $value['name'] ?></span>
</label>

<?php } ?>
```

**Controller Code:-**

```
public function insertData(){

$option1 = $this->input->post('option1[]');
$option2= $this->input->post('option2[]');

var_dump($option1);
var_dump($option2);


for ($i = 0; $i < count($option2); $i++) {
   $data = array(
       'option1'=>$option1[$i],
       'option2'=> $option2[$i]);
       
   $this->db->insert('table_name',$data);
}

}
```

Comment: thanks for helping me. I'm so sorry maybe I miss match with my question in in this forum. But with your answered, I got an idea two days ago and I have fixed it. Thank you